# Bulk insert showing BOM character(∩╗┐) while reading from txt file in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, utf-8, bulkinsert

I have a script with which I am trying to load data stored in a `.txt` file using SQL Server. The text file is stored as UTF-8 encoding. The data read from the txt file showing bom character appended to the first line of data. I am using SQL Server 2012 version.

How can I avoid the bom character while reading?

Here's what I have tried:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1(record nvarchar(512))

BULK INSERT #Temp1
FROM 'C:\Test\test.txt'
WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')

SELECT * FROM #Temp1
```

Temp table result is shown as:

[image]

`test.txt` is as below

[image]

Comment: This sounds likea coallation issue. What is the coallation of your db?

Comment: Also, open the file in notepad++ too see if there are any funky characters

Comment: More problems may be lying ahead (even with the bom issue solved) if you keep the utf8 file encoding with SQL2012. The safest bet would be to convert the utf8 file to unicode (since data will be stored in Nvarchar) beforehand and then bulk insert it.

Comment: @DougCoats   coallation  is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: this might be helpful https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182700/encoding-issue-with-sql-server-varchar-column-retrieved-in-python